# How to seek political asylum in the DPRK or the PRC

Tags: asylum

I'm the current chairman of the PKI-Maois ( Communist Party Indonesia Maoist ) and me and several members of our party had tried to find a way to seek political asylum in the DPRK or the PRC.

Does anyone have any kind of information on the procedure to obtain asylum in the two countries?

Comment: "Does anyone have any kind of information on this?" is too broad for this site. Can you make your question more specific? First, you should pick a single country, since the DPRK and PRC are very different countries. Are you wondering whether whether these countries offer asylum? Or how you'd go about applying for asylum?

Comment: The DPRK we have an official OD but their embassy is very difficult to get in contact with so the question was more about the PRC as a 2nd option basically the 1st choice to us is the DPRK but the PRC is a 2nd option we would see a good option.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is not clear what kind of information you are looking for. Can you be more specific about what your question is? In fact I am not even sure if it's on-topic here. For advise about migrating to other countries, including through the asylum process, there is https://expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's about seeking political asylum in either the DPRK or China, And as a Communist we are not interested in going to Europe or America we want asylum in a country like China or the DPRK.

Comment: China would be fine (although intellectual consistency might cause you to reject asylum there due to China's own past and to some extent current record of [slavery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_China) and colonialism, to say nothing of imperialism) but if you're at all sane, don't seek asylum in the DPRK.

Comment: @SujarnoMalaka OK, but *what questions* do you have about seeking asylum in the DPRK or China? Please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about that (and if you are who you claim  to be, which seems dubious), simply ask the respective embassies. They might indicate if they would grant asylum either in the respective countries or in the embassies.

Comment: Actually i am who i am who i say i am and our own website: http://pki-maois.wixsite.com/pki-maois problem is and we have an official OD to the DPRK of one of our party members. Contacting the embassy of the DPRK is not always easy.

Comment: Could it be that they do not want to be contacted by you in this matter? That would be a strong indication of their answer.

Comment: I think we had been very supportive on the DPRK in many ways i could not say online but either way we even have an official delegate, And done a lot of things for their government which i could not mention online as well

Comment: @SujarnoMalaka, even mentioning that you helped them makes me think that this is a false flag operation to discredit Maoists.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Trilarion, if I wanted to talk to a foreign government (which I don't), I'd go to the embassy. That's the answer. My qualifier that I don't believe the question is genuine is indeed a comment.